# In the Terminal on Mac OSX, How to use shift + arrows in order to select text?

Tags: macos, terminal, keyboard-shortcuts

I have been using terminals to code for a while on Fedora. On the native terminal of Mac, i found something very disturbing:

I can't select text with the combination of SHIFT + arrows or others keyboard combinations. It is really painfull to use the mouse to select something and even that when i have selected some text with the mouse i can't use backspace in order to delete selected text.

is there anyway or any application on mac in order to get that keyboard shortcut ?

See you soon !

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/125190/select-text-from-terminal-app-using-the-keyboard-in-os-x

Comment: Where will you be seeing me? That's kind of creepy...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this Macword article](http://www.macworld.com/article/1059321/termtext.html), and it's [referenced MacOSXHints.com tip](http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20060115014737999)… it is possible to enter `Start Keyboard Selection` mode, via a keystroke…

<kbd>Option</kbd> + <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd>

This was written back *when 10.4 was new* and for ME.. on 10.8.3 DOES NOT work.  Hopefully this info may lead you to a solution that DOES WORK. You can [watch a movie of THEM doing it here](http://media.macworld.com/media/legacy/2007/08/downloads/termtextpasteb.mov).